# Create pfx file from Symantec code signing certificate

Tags: ssl, code-signing

We have a password-protected pfx file, expiring in a few days, which we use to sign our exes.

We have renewed our SSL certificate from Symantec, but all we have received is a bunch of data:

```
Below is your Code Signing certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Below is the intermediate CA certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Below is your certificate in pkcs7 format:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have seen a few tutorials to create pfx files from .cer and .key files, but the fun part is, Symantec doesn't use the same terminology as the rest of the world. So I don't know which is which. And no single tutorial explains what should be in the files, so I can't go from there either. So, I don't know how to create the .key file, for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the main requirement is to install the certificate on a browser, **from the computer that has made the request for a new certificate**.

Then, most browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) can export it to PFX from the installed certificates list.

More info can be found here:

- http://blog.ksoftware.net/2011/07/exporting-your-code-signing-certificate-to-a-pfx-file/
- http://blog.ksoftware.net/2011/07/exporting-your-code-signing-certificate-to-a-pfx-file-from-firefox/
- https://knowledge.verisign.com.sg/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=AR190&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1360582675798